# .net DrawString Hebrew font with zero-width characters

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, graphics, fonts, drawstring

Are there any additional properties or parms in the DrawString to solve this problem. 
I have a Hebrew font with many zero-width characters so that two characters should render in the same location.

This example shows the .NET problem on the left, and what is should look like on the right:

http://hebrewresources.com/html5/images/rendering_issue.png

Word and Visual Studio text boxes render the same way, but in SumTotal'sToolbook, it renders correctly.

This is actually a very old true-type font from over 15 years ago, 
and it's not even right-to-left.  I may switch to newer font, but then 
I would have to write a program to remap every character and vowel.

```
objGraphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
objGraphics.DrawString(text, objFont, Brushes.Black, border / 2, border / 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to:

```
objGraphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
var stringFormat = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft);
float x = border / 2;
float y = border / 2;
objGraphics.DrawString(text, objFont, Brushes.Black, x, y, stringFormat);
```

If it doesn't work, you will have to try other flags:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.stringformatflags(v=VS.71).aspx

Comment: Like I said, my font was really created before right-to-left fonts existed, I just now tried that option, and nothing printed at all.  I also tried NoWrap, NoFontFallback, NoFit, and FitBlackBox.  They all print letters, but looks same as in my original post.